# Can't find the Texel Density Checker addon in the addons list

Tags: uv, add-on

I'm a newbie with Blender.

I have downloaded the latest version of the [Texel Density Checker](https://github.com/mrven/Blender-Texel-Density-Checker/releases/) from both the GitHub and Gumroad sites. So as always to add a new addon, I go to the *Edit* menu and then to *Preferences* and in the addons menu, I chose *Install*. Till there is nothing special, I go to the appropriate folder where the addon is downloaded, select my zip file (Texel_Density_3_3_1_291.zip) then click *Install*.

Then in general you see the addon, you check the box and it's active. But here, it's not the case. A message appears at the bottom: Modules Installed () from `C:\\Users\\...\\Downloads\\Texel_Density_3_3_1_291.zip` into `C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.3\\scripts\\addons`.

But in the end, there's no *Texel Density Checker* addon in the list. I went to the folder: `Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.3\\scripts\\addons`, but there's nothing corresponding to that addon.

For info, I'm using the 3.3.0 version of Blender. So my question is has someone faced that situation with that addon or even with another one and what is the solution? Do I have to go back to an earlier version of Blender?

Comment: i would recommend asking the creator of the add-on....

Comment: It installed fine under Blender 3.3 here and is visible in the N panel of the UV editor. You don't have Enabled Addons Only checked on the Preferences Addons tab do you?

Comment: Make sure the "Community" filter button is active. After the installation, move the mouse pointer to the addon list. It should update and display the addon then. (Tested with Blender 3.3 and it works for me.)

Comment: Thanks guys for your replys. But after many attempts of removing and reinstalling the addon, I was finally able to find the addon with the search window, search wich was failing before. Anyway, I don't understand why it dindn't appear right after having installed it. In general you install it, it appears and you check it.

Comment: At the end it works but I don't know what exactly I have done for it... Strange!  But anyway, again thanks for your replys.